# How to hide a debug action in code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs

Is it possible to hide the following "Debug" link between 9 and 10 lines?

[image: debug link in code]

Either in Jest tests or in all code.

These links are very annoying. For example the file contains 20-50 tests. When I edit the file all these 20-50 links disappear. And when I save the file the links are added again. On each edit/save iteration all lines are shifted. I have a headache because of this kaleidoscope :)

Comment: find a Codelens setting for your language extension

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've found the corresponding CodeLens setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeLens shows the debug action. It can be customized for Jest using the following settings:

```
    "jest.debugCodeLens.showWhenTestStateIn": [
        "fail"
    ]
```

The action will be shown only if a test was failed. If one will specify an empty array of states, then the action will be always hidden.